# How can I remove an specific button in tkinter after creating various of them with the same function?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, tk-toolkit

So I'm programming my first GUI with Tkinter for a project I have in mind and I'm having a lot of trouble with one essential step for this project. To summarize, I need to create a button that simply adds more buttons. Here is my code for this button:

```
room_frame_number = 0
def add_room_frame():
    global room_frame_number
    room_frame_number += 1
            
    room_Button = tk.Button(rooms_frame, text = "This is room number " + str(room_frame_number))

    add_button.pack_forget()
    room_Button.pack()
    add_button.pack()


add_button = tk.Button(rooms_frame, text = "Add", command = add_room_frame)
add_button.pack()
```

Now, what I'm having problems with is the following: when I click one of those newly created buttons, the command I want to activate is one that erases the clicked button.

I know I need to use the `pack_forget()` method at some point, but all I have tried gave me problems. Please, I would appreciate so much a bit of orientation with this issue.

Comment: You are removing the button, then again using ```.pack``` in the function ```add_button.pack()```

Comment: If you're re-packing an existing button, you don't need to call `pack_forget`. Calling `pack` will replace any previous calls to `pack` on the same widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button to be  able to delete itself, you can do it like this:

```
room_Button = tk.Button(rooms_frame, text = "This is room number " + str(room_frame_number))
room_Button.configure(command=room_Button.destroy)
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much! I don't know why I didn't try that one before